# how to expand child on particular Button click in Expandable List View

Tags: java, android, xml

How to expand child on particular Button click in Expandable List View rather than Group click

Comment: Show us what you have tried first

Comment: ExpandableListView view1=view.findViewById(R.id.exp);
  view1.expandGroup(0);

Comment: view1.expandGroup(0); not working

Answer (score 0):

Open your activity_main.xml and try like this example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/laptop_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For group view, create corresponding xml file and try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/laptop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For child view,create corresponding xml file and try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/laptop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no luck...its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...
Adapter Class

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; 
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity class**

```
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

// get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



 private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("Top 250ddfffd");
            listDataHeader.add("Now Showingddfdddf");
            listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..ddf");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> top = new ArrayList<String>();
            top.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
            top.add("The Godfather");
            top.add("The Godfather: Part II");
            top.add("Pulp Fictionssss");


            List<String> nowss = new ArrayList<String>();
            nowss.add("The Conjuring");
            nowss.add("Despicable Me 2");
            nowss.add("Turbo3333");
            nowss.add("Grown Ups 234343");


            List<String> coming = new ArrayList<String>();
            coming.add("2 Guns222");
            coming.add("The Smurfs 2333");
            coming.add("The Spectacular Nowsss");
            coming.add("The Canyonssss");
            coming.add("Europa Reportssssss");

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); 
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowss);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), coming);
        }
```